# Sorting things to match information on a column

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, vba

Watch this example:

[image: example]

I have all the possible information in the first column, the second one only has the information of what exists phisically. The row starting on that second column shows the information of what exists.

Is there any way to sort things out like this?

[image: Sorted things]

I've tried sortings things out alphabetically, and it didn't work as I demonstrated. Also note that this is only an example.
In my main sheets things are not properly near one another yet my point stands.

I accept either macro or formula answers, thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this without applying a macro, is that an acceptable solution?

Comment: @erikdaude as I stated in my question : "I accept either macro or formula answers, thank you."

Comment: Yes I don't see how you could do it in situ without VBA, but if you were prepared to duplicate the contents of column C somewhere else and do a lookup on columns D:G you could use a VLOOKUP or MATCH/INDEX formula.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: @FreeMan thank you for the welcome message. The problem is that I don't know how to start codewise, so I wanted to know if there was a formula. Since there is none, I still don't know how should I start. I'd post the code I had if I had any.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
In your vba ide you will have to got tool -> reference and select
"Microsoft ActiveX Data Ovjects 2.8 Library"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SortExisting()
Dim rsPossible As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rsExists As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lFind as Long

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.  You can store sums here.
    With rsPossible
        .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
        .Fields.Append ""Possible", adChar, 20
        .Open
    End With

    With rsExists
        .Fields.Append "Exists", adChar, 20
        .Fields.Append "Value1", adChar, 30
        .Fields.Append "Value2", adChar, 33  'Make the fields as big as they need to be.
        .Fields.Append "Value3", adChar, 20
        .Open
    End With

    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the columns.
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        rsPossible.AddNew
        rsPossible.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
        rsPossible.Fields("Possible").Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value
        rsPossible.Update

        rsExists.AddNew
        rsExists.Fields("Exists").Value = ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value
        ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = ""
        rsExists.Fields("Value1").Value = ws.Range("E" & lRow).Value
        ws.Range("E" & lRow).Value = ""
        rsExists.Fields("Value2").Value = ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value
        ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = ""
        rsExists.Fields("Value3").Value = ws.Range("G" & lRow).Value
        ws.Range("G" & lRow).Value = ""
        rsExists.Update

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop

    If rsExists.EOF = False Then
        rsExists.MoveFirst
    End If

    'Here we loop through the existing
    Do While rsExists.EOF = False
        "Find the current existing in th
        rsPossible.Filter = ""
        rsPossible.Filter = "Possible='" & rsExist.fields("Exists").Value
        lFind = rsPossible.Fields("Row").Value

        'Write the value of the existing to the row of the possible
        ws.Range("D" & lFind).Value = rsPossible.Fields("Exists").Value
        ws.Range("E" & lFind).Value = rsPossible.Fields("Value1").Value
        ws.Range("F" & lFind).Value = rsPossible.Fields("Value2").Value
        ws.Range("G" & lFind).Value = rsPossible.Fields("Value3").Value

    rsExists.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: There are some errors in that code, it gives me syntax error in :
`.Fields.Append ""Possible"", adChar, 20`  And you forgot to finish a comment line `"Find the current existing in th`

Comment: Also where do I assign that macro, I'm not finding a way to assign it to a button or anything.

Comment: @Atheisthotdog I fixed the extra quote, my bad.  To 'assign' it to a button simply take the body of the sub and put it into the button event of your liking, probably the click event.  So everything between Private Sub SortExisting()   and   End Sub

Comment: it still gives me syntax error in `.Fields.Append ""Possible", adChar, 20`

Comment: change .Fields.Append ""Possible", adChar, 20  to  .Fields.Append "Possible", adChar, 20    Take out the extra "

Comment: @MattheyD I fixed everything in your code to make it run, now it gives me `Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.`

Comment: @Atheisthotdog  It is probably in the rsExists field appends.  I mistakenly had those as integers.  change adinteger to adChar.   And if you have values more that 20 char you will need to make that bigger as well